# How to animate div linearly using mouse wheel scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am able to scroll the div from right to left side but I have to display the div linearly when scrolling the mouse wheel.Current code is not displayed liner
. I mean I have to display smoothly from right to left.

Would you help me out in this?

```js
(function() {
    function scrollHorizontally(e) {
        e = window.event || e;
        var delta = Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, (e.wheelDelta || -e.detail)));
        document.getElementById('gentags').scrollLeft -= (delta*40); // Multiplied by 40
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    if (document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener) {
        // IE9, Chrome, Safari, Opera
        document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("mousewheel", scrollHorizontally, false);
        // Firefox
        document.getElementById('gentags').addEventListener("DOMMouseScroll", scrollHorizontally, false);
    } else {
        // IE 6/7/8
        document.getElementById('gentags').attachEvent("onmousewheel", scrollHorizontally);
    }
})();
```

```css
#gentags {
position:relative;
margin-top: -.25em;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: hidden;
}

#gentags > div{
    overflow: hidden;
    width:200%;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0px;  /* remove scrollbar space */
    background: transparent;  /* optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
/* optional: show position indicator in red */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: transparent;
}

.horizontal_scroll .full_screen_100 article{
    width: 12.58%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    border-left: solid 1px #E2E2E2;

}
```

```html
<div id="gentags">
   <div class="horizontal_scroll">
  <div class="full_screen_100" id="left_scroll">
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">01</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">02</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">03</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">04</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">05</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
   <article><div><p class="scroll_number">06</p><span class="page_slogan">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, </span></div></article>
  </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I haven't rellay understood. I am able to scroll the content horizontally via mousewheel. What should be "linear" about it? Do you want to perform a horizontal scroll from left to right, started by any mousewheel movement?

Comment: **[This might help](https://codepen.io/matths/pen/yjbis)**

Comment: @Jaspa, Thanks for the reply. Check this link https://www.tentwenty.me/about-us and effect when scrolling it.

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, Thanks for the reply, Please check the above link, I need when mouse wheel scroll happen than I have to slide linearly.

Comment: @Jaspa, any help in this?

Comment: That's a really tricky one. I've never seen something like this before (and frankly, I don't recommend this for user-experience's sake). I am looking into it and then I tell you whether I got something

Comment: @Jaspa, Thanks for the reply, I hope you understand my issue.

Comment: I do. I am going to post a simple solution throughout the day, but it is not as good as the one in your example

Comment: @Jaspa, Do you know about this tool https://greensock.com/get-started-js

Comment: I think they used this tool for animation on mouse scroll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(This answer was rewritten entirely)

I've checked your JSFiddle code and found the reason, why it is always scrolling with the same speed.
Your new scroll postion was always `currentPosition + wheeldelta`. But that results in a constant scroll speed.

The solution (as in the previous answer): Calculate the END of the current scroll animation and increment it with every wheel rotation. Means: You need a global counter for the virtual (=at the end of aniamtion) page scroll position (xScroll). It's initialized to 0 and gets incremented by a speed value every time the wheel event is fired. And then you scroll to this new xScroll.

There are still some issues, though:
1. The user could scroll further (and so change xScroll), even if the scrollbar has reached either the left or right side of the content. If the user scrolls now into the other direction, xScroll is still too big (or small), resulting in delays of the visible animation's start. To avoid those overshoots, I introduced limits for xScroll - in fact zero (completely left) and the width of scrollable content (completely right).
2. Every browser provides different deltas for one mouse rotation, resulting in huge speed differences when using deltaY to calculate the new xScroll. To solve this, we only determine the rotation direction (delta > or < 0) and negate or not negate a self-chosen speed value (in my case 120). Now, every time the wheel is rotated, the end of the smooth scroll animation is either incremented or decremented by 120px - depending on the scroll direction.
3. Currently, we are only listening to the wheel event and update our xScroll every wheel rotation. But if the user scrolls via scrollbar and then switches to mousewheel again, xScroll has a wrong value, as the wheel event is not fired by the bar. That results in scroll position jumps back and forth. But we cannot simply update xScroll to the current scroll position everytime the scroll event was fired, because then the smooth animations would suddenly stop (as their end xScroll is now set to the current scroll position). The solution is pretty dirty, but works: A global flag `ignore`, true if the current call of scroll event was initiated by mousewheel or it's following animation, false if not (-> initiated by scrollbar). If ignore is false, xScroll is updated on every scoll event, otherwise not.

It sounds very complicated and seems also pretty dirty to me, but it works on up-to-date-browsers.

What I couldn't achieve is a smooth scrolling even when user scrolls via scrollbar. But I think, this is not really necessary. Actually I think this horizontal scroll gives a pretty bad user experience (what happens on phones?), but hey, that's not the question.

Your original fiddle: jsfiddle.net/3s5su2q3/6/

My solution: jsfiddle.net/3s5su2q3/14/

P.S.: Your event listeners were deprecated. In my solution I used the new standard (compatibility: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent). Feel free to add support for older browsers, though.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @jaspa, I checked your code. using mouse wheel not able to scroll.

Comment: Now the issue is when I scroll little bit mouse wheel it's working smoothly but when I scroll fast mouse wheel it's also working the same. I mean check the scroll bar speed. Slow and fast both effect is showing same. I need if slow mouse wheel then smooth slowly article if fast mouse wheel then the smoothly fast article. like above sample site. I am using GSAP tool for animation.

Comment: Using Firefox 57 (i.e. Quantum), this doesn't work - `xScroll` always returns `NaN`

Comment: Could you please recheck? I posted a version of when I was working on the code. With the now given link, it works for me (FF 57 also)

Comment: @Jaspa, I am relay appreciate your answer.I checked your updated answer But I think there might be little bit issue with the scroll. I mean I have 9 articles and When I am scrolling it then it scrolling till articles 5.

Comment: @Jaspa, Yes, I checked that so what I did, I added var innerWidth=document.getElementById("scroll_container"); and also added the id="scroll_container" and change the css from #gentags > div{ overflow: hidden;width:400%;} to #gentags #scroll_container { overflow: hidden;width:400%;} but same issue

Comment: @Jaspa, My 99% issue got resolved and 1 % I found the issue. That issue is if you notice that you scroll at the end. Now you want to go reverse then scrollbar not talking any event. If you scroll continue min 10 to 20 sec then it's going to the left side.

Comment: I checked in the chrome and safari. Their scroll event is working fast. In Mozilla, it's working perfectly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159745/discussion-between-narendra-verma-and-jaspa).

Comment: How can I do that? ^^

Comment: @Jaspa, I will hide the X scrollbar so that user can scroll the only mouse wheel.

Comment: Click on let us continue this discussion

Comment: @Jaspa, I check It's working on window  but it's not working on MAC(Chrome,FF, Safari)

Comment: No problem @Jaspa, You help me a lot. I really appreciate.I will accept this answer and upvote from my side. I upload one question here if you can help me. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47482832/on-scroll-animation-using-gsap/47483997#47483997